# How to add a data value to a cypress test

Tags: testing, automated-tests, frontend, cypress

I am having issues adding a data value to a cypress test.  I want to test if the data-values exist

The data-value is below:

`data-value="{ "id": "1", "name": "GBR"}"`

when I add the test

`cy.get('[data-value="1"]').should('exist')`

It always comes back with a syntax error, I've tried it a few different ways but no luck.

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

One way is you can directly verify the entire value `{ "id": "1", "name": "GBR"}`

```
cy.get('selector').should('have.attr', 'data-value', `{ "id": "1", "name": "GBR"}`)
```